# Does sharing a page in SPO externally also grant access to documents/lists on that page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

I have managed to share a page containing a customised list I created as a web part successfully.

However, after sharing the page externally, I cannot seem to view or access the list on the shared page!

Do I also have to grant them (external users) separate permissions to the list on that shared page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant permissions to list or list items too. Giving permissions to page is not enough.